# Me Menu is broken

Tags: 10.10, applet, pidgin, gwibber, memenu

The Me Menu on the top panel does not let me type a status to post to Gwibber or Pidgin. It simply is a grayed-out box that says "Post message..." I cannot type into it. Also, the status selector only works (not grayed out) when Pidgin is logged in; I cannot go from offline to available.

I already tried re-installing indicator-session, indicator-applet-session, indicator-me, gwibber, and gwibber-service, and removing and re-adding the applet.

Edit: Here's the console output when running Gwibber. It throws some errors, but none seem to be relevant.

```
** (gwibber:7611): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowState' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (gwibber:7611): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowActions' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (gwibber:7611): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowMoveResizeMask' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags' /usr/bin/gwibber:73: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed  gtk.main()
```

Comment: AFAIK the status selector will work only after logging in to Pidgin.By normal it's greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, the status selector only works
>   (not grayed out) when Pidgin is logged
>   in; I cannot go from offline to
>   available.

I think this is a "feature" -- you need first start an IM client to control it from MeMenu.

Same with Gwibber -- you need to start Gwibber manually (ar add it to startup application) and then you'll be able to write messages...

Editor: Problem with switching back to available after setting "offline" is known bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-me/+bug/550824

Comment: When Pidgin is open but set to offline, the status selector doesn't work, but it activates when I go available.

Comment: On the other hand, the status box just doesn't work at all, even if Gwibber is opened. gwibber-service is running at startup.

Comment: Yes, the offline→avaialble "thing" is known bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-me/+bug/550824

Comment: Maybe there's a little misunderstooding -- the "Post message" box is not for settings status text in Pidgin/Empathy -- it's for sending messages via Gwibber to services like Twitter, Identi.ca or Facebook...

Comment: Okay, I understand the Pidgin/Empathy<->Me Menu limitations now.

Comment: That leaves the Gwibber non-functionality issue.